# How to sign Microsoft Dynamics CRM Plugin with my own certificate from my CA

Tags: certificate, dynamics-crm-2011, ssl-certificate, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

We are developing for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011, mostly we do CRM plugins.
By default, when publishing CRM plugin, Visual Studio uses self-signed certificate from developers computer.
We do have our own Certificate Authority (Windows Server 2012), and we have enabled Code Signing Certificate Template.
We have accomplished that developer access CA web (/certsrv/) and puts Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and gets certificate.

After CA issues certificate, we have .pfx file which includes private and public key and we will replace default key.pfx (which stores self signed), so i believe this will be fine ?

Question is:
 - how can CRM developer in Visual Studio 2012 create/generate CSR for our CA
(certificate should not have developers name, only company name and info, and maybe CRM plugin name?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamics CRM Plugin Code signing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401633/dynamics-crm-plugin-code-signing)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you at all: [.NET - ClickOnce Install - Company Name and Application Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977625/net-clickonce-install-company-name-and-application-name)

Comment: The problem is not approval, problem is to create client signing request for application, visual studio does not have tool for this, i do not want that user info is displayed in final solution, it should be only company info